# Recommendation for good "complete siddur" (siddur shalem)

Tags: shabbat, product-recommendation, prayer-book, chagim-holidays, chol-weekday

Friends,

I am looking for a pocket-sized complete siddur (one that has weekday, Shabbat, holiday and High Holy Day prayers), and I am having trouble finding one. Complete siddurim seem to be hard to find. Does anyone have any thoughts on such a siddur?

ETA: Fair enough :)  I'm looking for something in Hebrew and English (my Hebrew davening abilities can best be described as "slight"), either nusach Ashkenaz or Ari. I really like the idea of having everything right there in one book that I can have with me at all times. This is at least in part because the siddur with which I really became observant in my prayer does not have a corresponding machzor, so I never knew exactly which machzor I should get if I want one.

Comment: jwlynn, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! Please [edit] in as much detail as you can about what you consider "good." What criteria would you use (and do you therefore want the community here to use) to evaluate suggestions and select one?

Comment: What siddur did you become observant with?

Answer (score 6):

Artscroll's סידור יצחק יאיר is a good choice, as a good, complete *siddur* with a clear print. It is the standard *siddur* used in most *shuls*. You can buy them in practically any Jewish book store, or online (for example, [here](http://zbermanbooks.com/?subcats=Y&status=A&pshort=Y&pfull=Y&pname=Y&pkeywords=Y&search_performed=Y&q=%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%99%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8&dispatch=products.search)). There is a pocket-sized edition of the *siddur*.

(Note: this *siddur* is *nusach Ashkenaz*; the Artscroll *nusach Sefard* equivalent is the [סידור תפילת שלמה](http://zbermanbooks.com/product-53414.html))

These *siddurim* contain the prayers for weekday, Shabbos, *chagim*, fast days, as well as High Holy Day prayers.

There are also English translations of these *siddurim* (with a running commentary), see [here](http://artscroll.com/Books/9780899066509.html) for an example of the older translation, and [here](http://artscroll.com/Books/9781422609682.html) for the newer English *siddur*, with an updated commentary.

Comment: Does that edition really contain High Holy Day prayers?

Comment: I just checked the table of contents of the Hebrew one; not sure about the translation.

Comment: Does it contain the actual prayers for the High Holy Days or just some supplementary procedures, such as *Tashlich*, *Hatarat Nedarim*, and *Simna Milta*? IIRC, Artscroll *siddurim* contain the latter, but not the former. For example see the ToC of [this English edition](http://artscroll.com/Books/9780899066509.html) (available online), which indicates sections for Rosh Hashanah and Erev Yom Kippur that contain only such supplementary procedures.

Comment: @IsaacMoses If I'm thinking of the right book, then it does. What it does not contain is the elaborate piyut-riddled repetitions of the Amida used by the the Chazzan in many congregations. In some congregations which do not have that practice, or when praying alone, this siddur should be sufficient.

Comment: To add to @DoubleAA's comment: the _sidurim_ under discussion omit not only _piyutim_ added to the _amida_ but also those added after the _amida_ of _maariv_ (which most communities say in my very limited experience) and elsewhere in the _RH_ and _YK_ prayers.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Looking at ToC now, it has shemoneh esrei for RH (page 320) and YK (335), but I am not sure if they have all the _piyutim_ also....doesn't look like it.

Comment: Also, @IsaacMoses, I did not check the ToC of the English siddur....according to the one you linked to, it actually is **not** a "complete siddur."

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any all-inclusive siddur that includes everything you need - i.e. - every possible prayer for every day of the year including all the complete service (piyuttim) said for all the Rosh Hashannah and Yom Kippur prayers.

If you have seen the "combo" Birnbaum Rosh Hashannah / Yom Kippur High Holiday machzor (no longer in print), it was hefty. As it is, Birnbaum's machzor made you flip pages back and forth, a lot esp. for Kol Nidre & Ne'ilah services.

An all inclusive siddur would be so huge and hefty that you'd probably need a forklift to put it on the shtender :-) You'd have to have a pocket the size of Og's hand.

Answer (score 1):

The Birnbaum siddur comes with tefillot for practically the whole year. As it is out of print, I am unsure about finding a pocket-sized copy, although I have one at home so I know they exist. The only things I can think of which would need a separate volume are:

- Selichot (particularly for Yom Kippur)
- L'David Mizmor for Maariv (Rosh Hashannah and Yom Kippur)
- Poetry for the repetition of the Amidah
- Shir haMa'alot mimamakim (for 10 days and Hoshannah Rabbah)